# Is it possible to regrind beans?

Tags: brewing-process, beans, drip-brew, grinder

Is it possible to regrind beans?

I have about half a bag of very nice coffee in a semi-coarse grind, and I want to use a brew method (Melitta cone) that's more appropriate for a medium-coarse grind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a pretty good way to ruin a burr grinder. Worst case scenario, your burrs jam up so much that they can't spin and burn out your motor. A blade could help, but I'd argue that the inconsistent grind you'd get wouldn't be much of an improvement in cup quality anyway. Realistically you'd end up with some of your grinds unchanged, some at the size you want and some ground to dust. The different sized particles would extract unevenly and the dust is likely to clog the filter.

That said, you're not going to break a blade grinder by regrinding, so give it a shot and see how you like the results. At most you're out 20-50g of coffee.

Comment: I appreciate the warnings and advice on using a blade grinder. I just used the coarse grinds. It was ok with the Melitta cone, but I have other ideas. I may post another question.

Comment: It's not entirely black and white and a fact it ruins your burr grinder. James Hoffmann explains it well in https://youtu.be/6IjFfl-8Gu8

Answer (score 6):

With a blade grinder, yes.  They already just chop the pieces smaller and smaller until you stop, anyway.  With a burr grinder, it may be.  But I make no promises that it won't clog the feeder.  It's possible that the inflow may be greater than it can handle.

Answer (score 2):

The basic reply is "yes, that's possible". With a manual burr grinder.

The thread warns well about the risks and shortcomings of electric devices for the job. A manual burr grinder allows to control the coarseness and the speed at which the ground gets through.

This is how I do, luckily that is rare and usually in small quantities.